# What API function do I use for redirecting to external URLs?

Tags: 7, redirection

When writing a module, for redirecting to Drupal paths, one uses `drupal_goto`.

Is there some API function that I should use for redirecting to external pages?
Or is setting the `Location` with `drupal_set_header` the way to go?

PS I have to do some processing on the request; `mod_rewrite`/`mod_alias` on Apache-level or the Drupal `Path redirect` module, don't solve my problem.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should use [drupal_goto()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7) for internal and external redirections.

Use 'external' option for external redirections:

`drupal_goto($url, array('external' => TRUE));`

> drupal_goto($path = '', array $options = array(), $http_response_code
>   = 302)

**$options: (optional) An associative array of additional options, with the following elements:**

- **'query'**: An array of query key/value-pairs (without any URL-encoding) to
  append to the URL.
- **'fragment'**: A fragment identifier (named anchor) to append to the URL.
  Do not include the leading '#' character.
- **'absolute'**: Defaults to FALSE. Whether to force the output to be an
  absolute link (beginning with http:). Useful for links that will be
  displayed outside the site, such as in an RSS feed.
- **'alias'**: Defaults to FALSE. Whether the given path is a URL alias
  already.
- **'external'**: Whether the given path is an external URL.
- **'language'**: An optional language object. If the path being linked to is
  internal to the site, $options['language'] is used to look up the alias
  for the URL. If $options['language'] is omitted, the global $language_url
  will be used.
- **'https'**: Whether this URL should point to a secure location. If not
  defined, the current scheme is used, so the user stays on HTTP or HTTPS
  respectively. TRUE enforces HTTPS and FALSE enforces HTTP, but HTTPS can
  only be enforced when the variable 'https' is set to TRUE.
- **'base_url'**: Only used internally, to modify the base URL when a language
  dependent URL requires so.
- **'prefix'**: Only used internally, to modify the path when a language
  dependent URL requires so.
- **'script'**: The script filename in Drupal's root directory to use when
  clean URLs are disabled, such as 'index.php'. Defaults to an empty
  string, as most modern web servers automatically find 'index.php'. If
  clean URLs are disabled, the value of $path is appended as query
  parameter 'q' to $options['script'] in the returned URL. When deploying
  Drupal on a web server that cannot be configured to automatically find
  index.php, then hook_url_outbound_alter() can be implemented to force
  this value to 'index.php'.
- **'entity_type'**: The entity type of the object that called url(). Only
  set if url() is invoked by entity_uri().
- **'entity'**: The entity object (such as a node) for which the URL is being
  generated. Only set if url() is invoked by entity_uri().

**$http_response_code:** (optional) The HTTP status code to use for the redirection, defaults to 302. The valid values for 3xx redirection status codes are defined in RFC 2616 and the draft for the new HTTP status codes:

301: Moved Permanently (the recommended value for most redirects).

302: Found (default in Drupal and PHP, sometimes used for spamming search engines).

303: See Other.

304: Not Modified.

305: Use Proxy.

307: Temporary Redirect.

## Drupal 8

Drupal 8 has [removed drupal_goto function](https://www.drupal.org/node/2023537), for redirect to external URL see [this answer for the question: How do I redirect to an external URL?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/136666/2604).

Comment: Very good answer

Comment: +1 tunic (and Nikhil M for edit input) This answer is better than the official API docs: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7 (in your answer, the options array is comprehensively described). +1 also Oleg for recognition.