# How to go to external website from within a module?

Tags: 6, redirection

I have created a custom module in which when a user enters a valid id, it should them take them to an external website. The problem I am having is redirecting to the external website. The code I am using in my module is to do the redirection is:

```
  // clear out the output buffer
  ob_start();
  while (ob_get_status()) {
    ob_end_clean();
  }
  return header("Location: $external_url");
```

This doesn't work. What should I be using to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `drupal_goto` to redirect to a URL.

```
drupal_goto($external_url, array('referral' => $referral_url));
```

Comment: Is there a way to set the referring url as well?

Comment: you can add it as 2nd parameter, which generates http://www.yourexternalurl.com?referral=valueofreferral_url

Answer (score 1):

You should use drupal_goto()

This question is answered in more detail here:

[What API function do I use for redirecting to external URLs?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/49679/what-api-function-do-i-use-for-redirecting-to-external-urls)