# How to redirect to an absolute url?

Tags: forms

Through the code, I will wish my redirect the user to an absolute url.

I tested with drupal_goto () but it only works with relative urls. I wish to go to another domain that current_domain

thank you

Comment: drupal_goto(); should work... $path: (optional) A Drupal path or a full URL, which will be passed to url() to compute the redirect for the URL... Full URL works with drupal_goto();

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/49679/what-api-function-do-i-use-for-redirecting-to-external-urls

Comment: made to do as ca for ca works

drupal_goto ('http://google.fr', array ('absolute' => TRUE, 'external' => TRUE, 'https' => FALSE));