# How do I redirect to an external URL?

Tags: 8, uri

Drupal 7 has drupal_goto() that would allow redirecting to an external url.

The change record indicated that ControllerBase::redirect is the method to be called in D8.
https://www.drupal.org/node/2023537

This seems to work with internal drupal URLs but throws an error with external http urls -

```
[12-Nov-2014 21:00:22 Asia/Kolkata] Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: "Route "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oaut....." does not exist." at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/d8/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/RouteProvider.php line 147
```

What would be the ideal equivalent of drupal_goto in D8 to redirect to an external URL?

Answer (score 26):

With a route name on a Controller:

```
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

class MyControllerClass extends ControllerBase {

  public function foo() {
    //...
    return $this->redirect('user.page');
  }
}
```

With an absolute URL:

```
use Drupal\Core\Routing\TrustedRedirectResponse;

return new TrustedRedirectResponse('https://google.com');
```

On a form `RedirectResponse` doesn't work, then:

With a route name:

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  //...
  
  $form_state->setRedirect('user.page');
}
```

With an absolute URL:

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  //...

  $form_state->setResponse(new TrustedRedirectResponse('https://google.com', 302));
  // You can change the response code from 302 to whatever you need
}
```

Comment: Redirects to external URLs are not allowed by default, use \Drupal\Core\Routing\TrustedRedirectResponse for it.

Comment: TrustedRedirectResponse doesn't work. results in exception "The controller result claims to be providing relevant cache metadata, but leaked metadata was detected. Please ensure you are not rendering content too early"

Answer (score 2):

`return new RedirectResponse($absolute_url);` seems to work

Comment: Redirects to external URLs are not allowed by default, use \Drupal\Core\Routing\TrustedRedirectResponse for it.